# What happens when the return declaration is inside of the parenthesis when defining a function in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, return

What is the difference between the two functions below? I typed both of them into a playground but the second function does not output anything. What does it mean when you put the `-> Bool` on the inside of the parenthesis as opposed to the outside? Is it incorrect because I don't get any errors but it doesn't execute properly either. I have seen this in functions the use completion handlers such as `CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(_:completionHandler:)` but I don't understand what this means or how it is used properly, if at all.

**A 'normal' function:**

```
func aBasicFunction(string: String, anotherString: String) -> Bool {
    // things happen
    return true
}
```

**The function I do not understand:**

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, anotherString: String -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    return true // I think? Is this function actually supposed to return a Bool?
}
```

The second function above doesn't do anything in my playground (in my actual playground it has a print statement) but it also doesn't return any errors.

**Here is the `CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(_:completionHandler:)` function:**

```
CLGeocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print(error)
            }
    // more stuff...
    })
```

This may be a separate question but I think the answer is related. What does `-> Void in` mean? What is it returning here (or in this case *not* returning?

Also I am using Xcode 7 (Swift 2). Thanks!

Comment: `()->Void means a closure taking no arguments and with no return value`

Comment: What would happen if it were `()->Bool`? How do you retrieve that return value?

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining when I would want to use a trailing closure? The docs explain what it is but not what it is used for.

Comment: its mainly for completion handlers (shown in your 3rd snippet), so the function will execute, then when the function is finished it will run the code thats inside the closure. usually because the function runs something asynchronously and this completion handler will execute at a later stage. it does have other uses though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In swift, functions are first class citizens and can be passed as arguments to other functions.

Function types are defined by the syntax `() -> ()`. For example, you can define a function that takes to integers and returns their sum as `(Int, Int) -> Int`

When you define a function that accepts another function as parameter, you need to define the types of functions allowed to be passed in.

You function:

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, anotherString: String -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    return true 
}
```

expects two parameters: `string` of type `String` and `anotherString` of type `(String) -> Bool`, which is actually a function, not a String. Since you are passing a function and not a string, you should rename the parameter name to `complete` or `callback` or some other function name.

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, complete: String -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    // return true <-- Nothing to return, actually
    complete("some string")
}
```

Then, you would use it as this:

```
aWeirdFunction("hello", complete: { response -> Bool in 
  print(response) // <-- prints "some string"
  return true // must return a boolean 
})
```

In Swift, you can simplify the syntax when the last parameter is a function as this:

```
aWeirdFunction("hello") { response -> Bool in 
  print(response) // <-- prints "some string"
  return true // must return a boolean 
}
```

You can also name the parameters of the passed function:

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, complete: (anotherString: String) -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    // return true <-- Nothing to return, actually
    complete(anotherString: "some string")
}

aWeirdFunction("hello") { anotherString -> Bool in 
  print(anotherString) // <-- prints "some string"
  return true // must return a boolean 
}
```

And allow functions with multiple parameters:

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, complete: (anotherString: String, total: Int) -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    // return true <-- Nothing to return, actually
    complete(anotherString: "some string", total: 100)
}

aWeirdFunction("hello") { (anotherString, total) -> Bool in 
  print(anotherString, total) // <-- prints "some string", 100
  return true // must return a boolean 
}
```

Finally, those functions you can pass as arguments can also have return values. In your example, you are specifying that the functions being passed must return a `Bool`, since your type is `(String) -> Bool`. Here is how you would use it:

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, complete: (anotherString: String, total: Int) -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    // return true <-- Nothing to return, actually
    let result = complete(anotherString: "some string", total: 100)
    if result {
        print("result is true!") // prints "result is true"
    }
}

aWeirdFunction("hello") { (anotherString, total) -> Bool in 
  print(anotherString, total) // <-- prints "some string", 100
  return true // must return a boolean 
}
```

Hope that helps!

#### Bonus

If you find that one of your methods has a complex function type parameter, or that many of your methods require the same function type, you can create a `typealias`, which adds a lot of clarity:

```
typealias CompleteCallback = (anotherString: String, total: Int) -> Bool

func aWeirdFunction(string: String, complete: CompleteCallback) {
    // things happen
    // return true <-- Nothing to return, actually
    let result = complete(anotherString: "some string", total: 100)
    if result {
        print("result is true!") // prints "result is true"
    }
}

aWeirdFunction("hello") { (anotherString, total) -> Bool in 
  print(anotherString, total) // <-- prints "some string", 100
  return true // must return a boolean 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first function is a function which returns "Bool".

```
func aBasicFunction(string: String, anotherString: String) -> **Bool** {
    // things happen
    return true
}
```

Your second function is a function which returns nothing, and it takes two parameter named string and anotherString. Here another string is assigned to a function, which you have to pass while calling aWeirdFunction. anotherString accepts function/closure which takes input argument of type "String" and will return Bool.

```
func aWeirdFunction(string: String, anotherString: String -> Bool) {
    // things happen
    anotherString("Hello") // Calls the function which was passed as parameter
    return true 
}
```

Call it like this,

```
aWierdFunction("Hello", { str:String -> Bool in
print(str)
return true
})
```

To learn more about closure, visit - [More on Closure](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/)
HTH.

Comment: So if you were to use `str` in `aWeirdFunction` would the value be `true` or would be a string that prints itself? That (what I just said) doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Jake The closure written by me just returns true no matter what. This was just to show you an example. However you can modify the function and add few conditions based on which you can return true or false.

Comment: Yeah I know. What I meant was I don't really understand how you would use that input in the function? Why would you want to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jake if your question is, How I am handling the "str" parameter in the closure I have written. Then, here I am just printing value that is assigned to the str parameter while calling the closure. In this case, we are passing "Hello", anotherString("Hello"), so when closure executes, it will print Hello and returns true. HTH

Answer (score 0):

**-** Instead of stretching things, I would simply quote the things this way.....

**In Swift Callback mechanism is achieved using two ways:**

**-** `Delegates`

**-** `Closures`

What you just experienced is `Callback` using `Closure`

**Example:**

```
internal func calculateSum(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int, completion: (sum: Int)-> Void)
{
    let total = numberOne + numberTwo
    // putting the value into the completion handler, so its avail at the caller side
    completion(sum: total)
}


calculateSum(5,  5) { (sum) -> Void in
    print(sum)
}
```